# How to save Russian characters in a UTF-8 encoded file

Tags: php, utf-8, translate

OK so I have a PHP file with several strings of text in various languages.  For most languages like French or Spanish I just simply type in the characters.

The problem I have is with Russian language characters. The PHP file is encoded in UTF-8, how can I make sure that the Russian characters are both saved correctly and displayed correctly on the output web page... Is it just a case of pasting the text into the PHP file, or is there a way to guarantee the characters will be saved into the file correctly - perhaps converting it into HTML-like notation for example?

Obviously I am assuming the end user will have the correct encoding set in their web browser, I just want to make sure I got it all covered from my end.

I am using Notepad++ on Windows to edit my PHP file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your doctype is html declare `<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>` but if your doctype is xhtml then declare `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`.
Never assume that end-user will act correctly during your designs
If you already have some document, edit your document's meta tag for charset declaration and use notepad++ encoding>*convert to UTF-8 without BOM*, save your document, safely go on with your multilingual structure from now on.
php tag is irrelevant for your question since you don't mention about any database char setting.

Comment: Thanks.  The strings aren't stored in any database, just in the PHP file only hence why I've not mentioned anything about databases. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to tell browsers your encoding, place it inside your `<header>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

Or short version

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
```

That should be pretty enough for Russian characters to be correctly displayed on a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between Latin and Cyrillic characters in UTF-8. Both are just byte sequences. Configure your server or PHP script to send `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf`, and you are rather safe.

Your editor might have problems when the font you are using does not contain Russian characters. Choose another font then.

And please ignore the `<meta>` element recommendations. You don't need that: it is useless when your HTTP headers are correct, and maybe harmful if they aren’t.

Answer (score 0):

### Well you have to check 2 things

- To ensure that *.php is an UTF-8 file I use [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/en/). If file is not in UTF-8, I save
  it like that: http://stepolabs.com/upload/utf-8.png
- Then your website must have UTF-8 encoding in `<meta>` tag;

  > `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

  ... more about [metatagging](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations#quicklookup).

Finally if everything is done well - (format and meta declaration) all should be displayed properly!