# PHP DOMDocument saveHTML not encoding cyrillic correctly

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, domdocument

I use `DOMDocument` to manipulate html and php 7. The problem is that text shows good on page (cyrillic), **but when I go to "See HTML page source", it is not good**. It shows like this:
`&#1047;&#1076;&#1077;&#1089;&#1100; &#1086;&#1089;&#1085;`

What might be wrong? `<meta>` charset is utf-8. My code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
if (@$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding("<div>$body</div>", 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD)) {

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493678/loadhtml-libxml-html-noimplied-on-an-html-fragment-generates-incorrect-tags

    $container = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);
    $container = $container->parentNode->removeChild($container);

    while ($dom->firstChild)
        $dom->removeChild($doc->firstChild);

    while ($container->firstChild )
        $dom->appendChild($container->firstChild);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 
    $headlines = $xpath->query("//h2");
    // some code..

    return $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: Please verify your encoding document page : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927122/how-to-save-russian-characters-in-a-utf-8-encoded-file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with `$dom->saveHTML();`, you need to add the root node as a parameter, like this:

```
return $dom->saveHTML((new \DOMXPath($dom))->query('/')->item(0));
```

The suddenly it renders the page differently, with substitution. If it does not, double check the values of `$dom->encoding` and `$dom->substituteEntities`, they should read `UTF-8` and `TRUE`.

Comment: How did you know that, my friend? I read a lot of sources and nobody wrote  about this solution

Comment: From memory, I had the same problem with my own framework years ago. The shorter syntax would be `$dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement);`

Comment: @sirjay [Others found the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-loadhtml-not-encoding-utf-8-correctly) as well. The behaviour is [not document on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php). Also Google has [no results](https://www.google.nl/search?q=%2Blibxml+%2Bsavehtml+-php) about this, so it must be something within the SaveHTML function passing parameters to libxml, I doubt the PHP team knowns this, there is [no bug report](https://bugs.php.net/search.php?search_for=savehtml). It's something users found out for themselves.